# How to apply compiled function on list

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

Compile function output error: How to apply compiled function on list?

```
    mkCompileCode[vars_, code_, idx_] := 
    With[{fVars = Flatten[vars]}, 
    Compile[{{in, _Real, idx}}, Block[fVars, fVars = Flatten[in];
    code], RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]]

    vars = {x, y, z};
    df = Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 1];
```

Compiling the above function

```
    cdfs = mkCompileCode[vars, df, 1]
```

Compiled function does nt work on following list:

```
    p = {{-1.`, -1.`, -1.`}, {-1.`, -1.`, -0.75`}, {-1.`, -1.`, -0.5`}, 
         {-1.`, -1.`, -0.25`}};

    cdfs[p]
```

out:

```
   During evaluation of In[236]:= CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression          
   Function[{x,y,z},Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]-1] should be a machine-size real number. >>

  {Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 1], 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 1], 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 1], 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 1]}
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please investigate again in your approach, because it is not clear why you use `Function` at this place

```
mkCompileCode[vars_, code_, idx_] := 
 With[{fVars = Flatten[vars]}, 
  Compile[{{in, _Real, idx}}, Block[fVars, fVars = Flatten[in];
    code], RuntimeAttributes -> Listable]];

vars = {x, y, z};
df = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 1;

cdfs = mkCompileCode[vars, df, 1];

p = {{-1.`, -1.`, -1.`}, {-1.`, -1.`, -0.75`}, {-1.`, -1.`, -0.5`}, {-1.`, -1.`, -0.25`}};

cdfs[p]

(* {0.732051, 0.600781, 0.5, 0.436141} *)
```

Comment: nice code and useful. Is there a limit on `idx` i.e. the dimension of `in` ?

Comment: @tchronis There is always a limit, because we are working with machines having finite memory, but I'm not aware that the tensor rank (idx) is limited per definition.

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean? It is your code! I thought you knew what you were writing!?